# The flux of a vector field

Tags: gauss-law, vector-fields

This is probably a basic question. I'm actually taking a class that introduces me to Maxwell's equations. I am currently trying to make sense of the Gauss's law and have some difficulty understanding the flux of a vector field.

The book first starts by explaining the surface integral of a scalar field, using this:

$$ M = \int_S \sigma(x, y)~\mathrm{d} a $$

where $\delta a$ is a infinitesimal area of the surface and $\sigma$ a function returning the area mass density. So far so good for me.

But then it goes off explaining the flux of a vector field:

$$ M = \int_S \vec{A} \cdot \hat{n}~\mathrm{d} a $$

But now this section starts saying that this integral is over a vector field. Which I don't really understand since the dot product of two vectors gives back a scalar. What do I get wrong here?

Comment: You really get nothing wrong here. This is how the flux is defined. In the end you still integrate over a vectorfield since $n$ comes from the surface. Just the result you are getting is a scalar. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I would suggest considering the problem for simple surfaces. Pick a simple vector field and a simple surface, e.g. a plane, the surface of a cube, and do the integral with pen and paper. You will need to find dot product on each surface and then add. This will help you to get a feeling for what is happening. Good luck

Comment: As @tomtom1-4 said, you are really integrating over a scalar field, not a vector field. What does the book literally say? Maybe you misread something.

Comment: Keep in mind that the unit vector “n” is defined as being perpendicular to the surface.  With the dot product, you are finding the component of the field vector which is parallel to “n” and perpendicular to the surface. For flux, you are looking for the amount of field “crossing” the surface.

Comment: Thank you, guys. It appears I misread the introduction for the flux. It says "In Gauss’s law, the surface integral is applied not to a scalar function (such as the density of a surface) but to a vector field", but further down the road, it says the result is a scalar.

Comment: What book says that?  It's misleading and confusing, as you have proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've already understood what the book was saying. But, in case anyone else has this confusion, here's an answer:

In the first integral...

$$ M = \int_S \sigma(x, y)~\mathrm{d} a $$

...the function $\sigma(x,y)$ represents the component of the vector-field $\vec{A}$ orthogonal to the surface at each $da$. This is also known as the "flux-density." Its the rate of change of the "amount of vector-field" passing through that surface with respect to the area we're considering on that surface.

For example - if the vector-field represents the velocity of some fluid at each and every point in space, then the flux-density is the rate of change of the volume passing through that surface with respect to the area at each point $(x,y)$. By integrating the flux-density with respect to the area, you get the total flux - the total volume-flow rate through that surface.

This "flux-density" only considers the components of the original vector-field $\vec{A}$ orthogonal to the surface.

That is, if $\vec{A}$ is a velocity-field, we can't consider the velocity-field and the flux-density to be the same thing, because components of the velocity parallel to that surface don't add to the volume flow-rate of fluid through that surface.

The only situation in which the velocity-field and the flux-density are the same thing are if the velocity vectors are everywhere orthogonal to the surface under consideration.

In the case that they're not, $\sigma(x,y)$ then depends not only on the field, but on the orientation of the infinitesimal area passing through each point as well. This is where the second integral comes in.

In the second integral...

$$ M = \int_S \vec{A} \cdot \hat{n}~\mathrm{d} a $$

...the vector $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector orthogonal to each $da$ at every $da$, so that:

$$\vec{A}(x,y)\cdot \hat{n}(x,y)=\sigma(x,y)$$

By taking the dot product with the area unit vector, you're only considering the component of the field punching through each infinitesimal piece of area.

In a nutshell, the two integrals are two ways of writing the same thing, and the author of the book should've explained what $\hat{n}$ was before making the notational switch.

Best of luck with the rest of your studies!

---

This isn't part of the answer, but the Wikipedia article on flux currently has this banner:

[image]

So...although I didn't take the time to read it, I'd stay away from there for now, especially if this specific question is still confusing you!

Besides that, from a quick glance it looks to be a pretty well written wikipedia entry!

Alright, that's all!

Comment: perhaps it's better to be more explicit and write $\sigma(x,y) = \vec{A}(x,y) \cdot \hat{n}(x,y)$

Comment: @peek-a-boo fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, it may help to think of flux in terms of field lines. Sketches of fields usually contain a number of lines. The direction of the lines represent the direction of the field in each region. In a 3D sketch, the density of lines is usually proportional to the field strength. In a 3D sketch one can think of the flux as a count of the number of lines crossing a given area: field (lines/unit area) times area.  Since you only want the part of the field which is actually crossing the area, the dot product yields the component of the field which is parallel to the area vector (which is defined as being perpendicular to the area, and “out” if the area is a closed surface.